# PHP Array to represent Minutes

Tags: php

I want to create an array to represent minutes:

```
 array {01,02,03,04,...,60}
```

How can I automatic do that?

Comment: http://php.net/range not working for you?

Comment: But range do not add 0 ahead the numbers < 10. There is another command able to create 01,02,03...60?

Comment: In programming we always divide problems, because the functions we have do only the work partly. The key is to bring functions together, like outlined in the diverse answers. But just reading, you actually want to create some SQL query for MySQL, so you might want to use a function from Mysql for that. Add your code to the question, so it will become more clear what you actually want to learn about and you will get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$minutes = range(1, 60);
```

When printing:

```
foreach( $minutes as $minute ) {
      echo ( $minute < 10 ? "0{$minute}" : $minute ) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: But range do not add 0 ahead the numbers < 10.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento The internal representation doesn't need that, when printing, you can add the padding. It is very hard to do anything with the numbers if you store them as strings.

Comment: The problem is that represent Minutes, and MySQL save it as 01,02,03... So if I got without 0, it not recognize as a date.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento Ok just what are really trying to do here? Your problem is not this array at all, but specifying date format for MySql.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PHP function `range` to create the array:

```
$min = range(1,60);
```

Comment: But range do not add 0 ahead the numbers < 10.

Answer (score 3):

Get the [`range`](http://php.net/range), map it to [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) for your string formatting ([Demo](http://codepad.org/32RTs1gF)):

```
$minutes = array_map('sprintf', array_fill(0, 60, '%02d'), range(1, 60));
```

The result is what you ask for: Array of strings with the numbers 1 to 60, zero-padded on the left.

```
["01", "02", "03", ... , "60"]
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. If you want a list of minutes beginning with "00" then do this: array_map('sprintf', array_fill(1, 60, '%02d'), range(0, 59));

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do that

```
$my_array = array();
for($i=1;$i<=60;$i++)
{
     $my_array[] = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
}
```